# display contact list with checkboxes?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an android project and I would like to create an application that intercept the inbound calls.How to assign a check box at contact list, in order to be able to select multiple contact persons once?

Here is my code:

> //main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_reminder);
        manage =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.manage_reminders);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        manage.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.manage_reminders:

            break;
        case R.id.add_reminder:
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
              intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
              startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);


            break;

        }


    }
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
        {

          if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
          {        
              Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
              cursor.moveToNext();
              String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               String  name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              Toast.makeText(this, "Contect LIST  =  "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }//onActivityResult

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/

Just make an BroadcastReceiver that listens to:

```
android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
```

If the phone state is 'Ringing', then there is an incoming call.

```
TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE
```

Like:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                    String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incoming Number: " + phonenumber);
            }
    }
}
```

Now the phone number will be printed in logcat.

Comment: coould you please post a simple code? plz. I need to create a call reminder . So I need to first print the phone number when someone calls.

Comment: Hope this helps. You just need to register the broadcast receiver. With: RegisterReceiver(IncomingCallReceiver, *yourIntentFilter*)

Comment: thx very much for your help. I am going to test it. How can I assing a note reminder to a number? Do I have to create a list and assign a text message to each number. When I have an incoming call I just post the message with the number that appears?

Comment: I won't make the whole app for you :) Somethings you have to figure out for yourself.

Comment: i've posted my code. thx very much. i don't want you to make the app. could you please give me an example/ idea?